# If Queue is implemented using an array, then what will be it's worst case time complexity and how?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue, time-complexity

Queue is implemented using an array.
I need WORST CASE time complexity,
So, I thought
Enqueue will be O(1) and Dequeue will be O(n) because maybe element can be at the end of an array so it will take O(n) complexity to reach their and delete that element.
Is this logic correct?

Comment: A Queue is called a FIFO structure because the first element that gets in will be the first element out of the queue. So complexity will be O(1) considering that the element to be dequeued will always be in the same position of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will be O(1) you're effectively just changing the pointer to the last element to the one before it. Your queue should never search to find the end only contain a pointer to the last element.